# Get book properties of element on click in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a map function outputting a list of books to my Books component. On each li that is being returned by the map function i have an onClick event handler that calls a function openBook, this function simply displays the info of that clicked book to a div on screen.
My issue is that for some reason, when i pass parameters to the openBook function it only passes the last li element's title and author and it seems to run the function without even me clicking on a book.

How can i pass the title and author params to the created div when i click on a particular book?

Here's my code and what i've tried.

Books.js

```
function Books() {

  const {books} = useContext(BookContext) //{books} here is the array (API) with all books inside but as a state in the BookContext file

  function openBook(title, author) {
    const bookview = document.createElement('DIV')
    if(document.body.contains(document.querySelector('.bookview'))) {
      document.body.removeChild(document.querySelector('.bookview'))
    }
    bookview.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times close"></i> <h4>'+info+'</h4>'
    bookview.classList.add('bookview')
    document.body.appendChild(bookview)

    document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.body.removeChild(document.querySelector('.bookview'))
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="bookshelf">
        <ul>
        {
            books.map(book => {
              return <li onClick={openBook(book.title, book.author)}>{book.title} <span>{book.author}</span><i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i></li>
            })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  )
```

}

BookContext (just has some books info)

```
const [books, setBooks] = useState([
{
  id: 1,
  title: "Digital Fortress",
  author: "Dan Brown"
},
{
  id: 2,
  title: "Origin",
  author: "Dan Brown"
},
{
  id: 3,
  title: "The Lord Of The Rings",
  author: "J.R Tolkien"
},
{
  id: 4,
  title: "The Bourne Identity",
  author: "Robert Ludlum"
}
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the onClick like this

```
<li onClick={() => openBook(book.title, book.author)}><span>{book.author}</span><i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i></li>
```

Because in the way you have returned the function would get executed onLoad itself and the return value will be assigned to onClick.

But what you actually require is a function that needs to be executed onClick of the li

Comment: cool that works but can you explain why that works and not what i did?